# enum is switching different cases

Tags: swift

```
enum TriStateSwitch {

    case off, low, high

    mutating func next() {
        switch self {
        case .off:
            self = .low
        case .low:
            self = .high
        case .high:
            self = .off
        }
    }
}

var ovenLight = TriStateSwitch.low
ovenLight.next()
ovenLight.next()
```

When I try to run the instance for first time it gives me `high` and when I run the same instance for second time it showing me `low` I don't what is happening with the playground moreover I suspect the problem still with me.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: This is working fine for me, it starts with `low`, `high`, then `off`

Comment: @forfreelancer - what do you expect to see?

Comment: @forfreelancer Also - you've asked 9 questions, most of which have answers, none of which you've accepted. If one of them solved your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark ✅

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is changing the same instance, and your code acts sequentially on your instance. I'll see if I can explain:

Here we can see for each part of your code

1.

```
var ovenLight = TriStateSwitch.low
```

So we are .low

2.

```
ovenLight.next()
```

If we are .low (which we were) we hit this case:

```
case .low:
    self = .high
```

so we are high

3.

```
ovenLight.next()
```

If we are .high (which we were) we hit this case:

```
case .high:
    self = .off
```

so we are .off

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you add some print statements you'll find your enum is acting exactly as it should:

```
var ovenLight = TriStateSwitch.low
print("1. ovenLight = \(ovenLight)")

ovenLight.next()
print("2. ovenLight = \(ovenLight)")

ovenLight.next()
print("3. ovenLight = \(ovenLight)")
```

That outputs:

```
1. ovenLight = low
2. ovenLight = high
3. ovenLight = off
```

It starts out at low, which is how it's created. The fist time you call `next()`, it moves to high. The next time yo call `next()`, it moves to the off state.